# How did Hagrid know about the Time-Turners?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Half-Blood Prince*, Hagrid is upset that the trio haven't been to see him and then says they could've used the Time-Turners:

> “Ar, I always knew yeh’d find it hard ter squeeze me inter yeh timetables,” he said gruffly, pouring them more tea. “Even if yeh applied fer Time-Turners.”
>
> — Chapter 11 (*Hermione’s Helping Hand*)

how did he know about them? Is their existence general knowledge to the public or did someone mention it at the end of *Prisoner of Azkaban*?

Comment: What?  Where does Hagrid say that?  In what chapter, or at what timestamp in the movie?

Comment: HBP 11. Hermione's Helping Hand, they haven't taken CoMC and he's pissed so they finally manage a visit after the Quidditch Tryout and he talks about the TTs, and Hermione states that it was IN THE PROPHET that they got destroyed. Someone in the Department of Mysteries must have leaked information - cause they are certainly general knowledge after that. But Hagrid was already a teacher in PoA, so maybe all the teacher were made aware of the fact Hermione was using one, in case they ran into her, not letting her classmates catch her would have been hard enough.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two theories:

1. I believe, although I can’t find a reference now, that Hermione’s teachers were told about her Time-Turner. We know that it was definitely for academic purposes:

   > “It’s called a Time-Turner,” Hermione whispered, “and I got it
   >   from Professor McGonagall on our first day back. **I’ve been using it all year to get to all my lessons**. Professor McGonagall made me swear I wouldn’t tell anyone. She had to write all sorts of letters to the Ministry of Magic so I could have one. She had to tell them that I was a model student, and that I’d never, ever use it for anything except my studies…. I’ve been turning it back so I could do hours over again, that’s how I’ve been doing several lessons at once, see?”
   >
   > *Prisoner of Azkaban*, chapter 21 (*Hermione’s Secret*)

   As witnessed by Harry and Ron, it was not unusual for Hermione to appear spontaneously in the middle of the classroom. Her teachers would need to be told, so that they didn’t ask any awkward questions which blew her cover.

   Hagrid was her Care of Magical Creatures teacher, so he would have known about the Time-Turner through this arrangement.
2. Although Hagrid doesn’t remember reading that the Time-Turners were destroyed, he may have learnt of or recalled knowledge about them from their mention in *The Daily Prophet*. A recent jogging of his memory like this might prompt his comment.

Comment: well there you have it then, must've missed that bit about the daily prophet

Comment: One of the Trio mentions that they destroyed them all at the Department of Mysteries and that it was in the Prophet right after the quote you posted.

Answer (score 11):

The wording of Hagrid's comment about Time-Turners doesn't suggest that he actually knew Hermione had one:

> “Even if yeh applied fer Time-Turners.”

Rather, he's likely just using a wizardly turn of phrase similar to the real-world phrase, "If I could turn back time". It's probably common knowledge that time-turners are ministry-controlled devices which can only be acquired by submitting a formal application, so a wizard who wishes they had more time might wistfully say "I should apply for a Time-Turner..."

In Hagrid's case, he's just emphasizing that he understands how busy they were: even if they had Time-Turners, they still would have had too much work to do to afford idly hanging around with Hagrid. Little did he know that by sheer coincidence they had in fact used a Time-Turner before.

Furthermore, if he knew they had Time-Turners and was shaming them for not using them to make a little spare time to spend with him, why did he mention "applying" for them? He would have said "Even though yeh had a Time-Turner," or something to that effect.

Answer (score 7):

I like alexwlchan's second answer, but not the first. [This related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64393/why-did-snape-not-think-about-the-time-turner-when-sirius-was-saved) makes me think it was unlikely that the teachers of classes that didn't overlap knew about Hermione's Time-Turner. Professor Snape, when asked by Dumbledore how Hermione and Harry could have been in two different places at once, is at a loss.

I think there's a much simpler explanation. At the beginning of *Half-Blood Prince*, Dumbledore informs Harry that he has inherited Buckbeak from Sirius, and that Buckbeak will go to live with Hagrid under an assumed name. Hagrid would of course be baffled about why Sirius Black had Buckbeak. I imagine Dumbledore simply told Hagrid the entire story, including the fact that Hermione had a Time-Turner.